# Буква Ё в именах собственных: Перл-Харбор или Пёрл-Харбор?

Tags: орфография, ономастика, топонимика, е-или-ё, буква

Скажите, не могу разобраться, буква Ё в топонимах факультативна или обязательна при наличии словарной фиксации? Яркий пример — П(е/ё)рл-Харбор; даже на обложках книг пишется через Е. А вот "Грамма.ру" ответила, что верно через Ё, Пёрл-Харбор, сославшись на академический орфографический словарь русского языка (см. [здесь](https://orfo.ruslang.ru/search/word)). Отчего так и как следует писать по правилу, чтобы не ошибиться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из полного академического справочника.

В обычных печатных текстах буква ё употребляется выборочно. Рекомендуется употреблять ее в следующих случаях.

1. Для предупреждения неправильного опознания слова, напр.: всё, нёбо, лётом, совершённый (в отличие соответственно от слов все, небо, летом, совершенный), в том числе для указания на место ударения в слове, напр.: вёдро, узнаём (в отличие от ведро, узнаем).
2. Для указания правильного произношения слова — либо редкого, недостаточно хорошо известного, либо имеющего распространенное неправильное произношение, напр.: гёзы, сёрфинг, флёр, твёрже, щёлочка, в том числе для указания правильного ударения, напр.: побасёнка, приведённый, унесённый, осуждённый, новорождённый, филёр.

**3. В собственных именах — фамилиях, географических названиях, напр.: Конёнков, Неёлова, Катрин Денёв, Шрёдингер, Дежнёв, Кошелёв, Чебышёв, Вёшенская, Олёкма.**

[Употребление буквы ё в текстах разного назначения](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=11#pp11)

Comment: Ну хорошо, а с Перл-Харбором какова ситуация? Все словари рекомендуют писать его с Ё или возможно двоякое написание в целом, раз столько примеров с Е сразу находится?

Comment: @ShiKomarishe вы не можете заглянуть в словари сами? Да, в век интернета это сделать трудно... http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BB-%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80&all=x

Comment: Я не филолог, в нюансах не разбираюсь. Почему-то ведь во множестве книг на обложках пишут Перл-Харбор через Е — вопреки правилу об указании правильного произношения. Вдруг тут какие-то особенности есть; сам в этом я разобраться не смогу, какие бы словари не смотрел...

Comment: @ShiKomarishe здесь вопрос не в нюансах, а в двояком положении буквы Ё в русском языке. Как я говорил в комментарии под одним из ответов: главное -- единообразие. В справочнике Лопатина сказано: *рекомендуется*. На то есть основания в виде орфографического словаря, но традиция писать в собственных именах Е вместо Ё очень крепка (на мой взгляд -- к сожалению). Можете писать Ё, можете Е, но -- во всём тексте одинаково.

Comment: Ну вот, так уже понятнее стало))) С такими, как я, надо доходчиво)))